# Design a finite automaton that recognizes a word that begins with $a$ and even number of $b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata

**Given the language $$L=\{w\in\{a,b\}^*\mid\text{$w$ starts with $a$ and has a total of even $b$}\}$$ design a finite automaton that recognizes it.**

---

Consider $M=\bigl(\{q_0,q_1\},\{0,1\},\delta,q_0\bigr)$, where $\delta:\{q_0,q_1\}\times\{0,1\}\to\{0,1\}$ defined by

[image: Finite automaton]

but then I realized that $a$ appears once, when the statement does not say anything about that.

How could we find it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the pictured automaton your attempt at solution?

Comment: @saulspatz yes... is very bad? $\ddot\frown$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, parts of it are excellent, but it needs more work.  $q_1$ is the state with an even number of $b'$s so when you get a $b$ you should transition to a third state $q_2.$  Also, you haven't dealt with what happens when you're in state $q_1$ and you get an $a.$ The number of $b'$s doesn't change, so you stay in $q_1.$

Now you ought to be able to figure out the transitions from $q_2$ on your own.

I haven't been able to find free software to make transition diagrams, so I'll have to settle for a table.  This is for an NFA:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
 &a&b\\ \hline
A&B& -\\ \hline
B&B&C\\ \hline
C&C&B\\ \hline
\end{array}

Here $A$ is the initial state and $B$ is the final (accepting) state.  State $B$ indicates that we have seen an even number of $b\text{'}$s so far, and state $C$ indicates an odd number of $b\text{'}$s.

A DFA is much the same, we just need a fourth state $D,$ for strings that start with $b$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
 &a&b\\ \hline
A&B&D\\ \hline
B&B&C\\ \hline
C&C&B\\ \hline
D&D&D\\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: I am not able to continue... Is it not correct to add a loop containing $a$ in the transition $q_1$? So now it has $3$ loops.

Comment: If it is incorrect, well, $\delta(q_1,q_2)=a$, and then?

Comment: The two loops labeled $b$ from $q_1$ to $q_1$ are incorrect and should be removed.  If I can figure out how to post a transition diagram, I'll write an answer.

Comment: I am on mobile, but I think your automaton is [this (image)](https://imgur.com/a/6uA0zBX), where $1=A,2=B,3=C,4=D$. 1) I think it's not correct at all because the initial state has two different transitions ($a$ and $b$), where the word must start with only one ($a$). What do you think?

Comment: @manooooh The accepting state is still B, not D.

Comment: Oh you are right, but the word can continue to begin with "$a$" or "$b$".

Comment: Is it correctt?

Comment: Is what correct?  Obviously, I think my answer is correct, or I wouldn't have posted it.

Comment: I mean, I see that the initial state ($A=1$) has two transitions ($a$ and $b$) when it should be one (starts with $a$). Why am I wrong?

Comment: Because no string that starts with $b$ will be accepted.

Comment: So the final automaton is [this (image)](https://imgur.com/a/iTQ45fX), do you agree? If so, I still see that $A$ can start with $a$ or $b$ $\ddot\frown$. Sorry for long discussion.

Comment: Yes, that's right.